# Multiple if condition statements javascript/html

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a condition where:

- if A is true and B is not, then it displays error_message_1
- if B is true and A is not, it displays error_message_2
- if both A and B are NOT true, displays error_message_3

First I tried writing all conditions in the same if...else if statement but it was very confusing so I tried putting them in different if statements and the code for that is below. the problem with this is that the third condition statement is always overridden by the first condition.

Code using html and javascript:

```js
function calculatePrice() {
    var tourType;
    var payDate;
    var returnTrip;
    var extra = 0;
    var tourCost = 0;
    var discount = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        tourType = document.getElementById("ans" + i);
        if (tourType.checked == true) {
            tourCost += parseFloat(tourType.value);
        }
    }

    if (tourCost == 0 && discount !== 0) {
        alert("Please select a Tour type");
        return;
    }

    for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
        payDate = document.getElementById("date" + a);
        if (payDate.checked == true) {
            discount += parseFloat(payDate.value);
         }
    }

    if (discount == 0 && tourType !== 0) {
        alert("Please select a Payment date.");
        return;
    }

    for (var u = 1; u <= 1; u++) {
        returnTrip = document.getElementById("return" + u);
        if (returnTrip.checked == true) {
            extra += parseFloat(returnTrip.value);
        }
    }

    tourCost = tourCost - discount * tourCost + extra
    tourCost = parseInt(tourCost)
    if (tourCost == 0 && discount == 0) {
        alert("Please select a Tour Type and Payment Date.");
        return; 
    } else {
        alert("The approximate cost of the holiday is $" + tourCost);
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<p>Complete the form</p>
<form name="packages">
    <p>
        Tour type:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans1" value="3900"><label for="ans1">5-day Escape Tour</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans2" value="5100"><label for="ans2">7-day Splendour Tour</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans3" value="6600"><label for="ans3">10-day Best Tour</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        Payment date:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date1" value="0.1"><label for="date1">Before 1st November 2016</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date2" value="0.07"><label for="date2">Between 1st November and 31st December 2016</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date3" value="0.05"><label for="date3">After 31st December 2016</label>
    </p>
    <p> 
        <label for="return1">Click here if you want to include a return airfare from Australia:</label><input type="checkbox" name="return" id="return1" value="900"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculatePrice();"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
</form>
```

Basically what I tried to do at first was to see whether any radio buttons were selected and base my if conditions on those. i tried using if (button.selected) but since each radio button has a different id, it was too long and I didn't know how to group them into one variable which I can use.

Comment: Doesn't your `== 0`indicate `true`and your `!= 0`indicate `false`? If so, you're just messint up with those 2 in your 3rd condition, since you're comparing against `== 0` (which actually would be `true` instead of your desired false).

Comment: The first condition is odd. Discount is always going to be 0 because that's how you've initialized it. 

The second one compares tourType with 0 and tourType is a string. That means tourType !== 0 will always be true as !== compares value without type coercion.

Comment: @Cosu tourType is a variable that holds a value which is an integer so i'm trying to compare that value to 0. Am i doing it wrong and is there another way to do it?

Comment: the only place where you're setting tourType is here `tourType = document.getElementById("ans" + i);` . This means it holds a dom element not a number or string. Because your first for loop has no break condition it will `tourType` will always be the last element in the for loop, the one corresponding to the element with id `ans3`. 

I would first figure out which option was selected. The first for loop is a good start but you need to add a break statement when you find the checked radio. Do the same for pay date. Once you're sure you have the tour and paydate extract the values

Comment: TO answer a question about how to structure an `if` statement, we don't need fifty lines of your code. Please replace it with a real simple example.

Answer (score 0):

> - if A is true and B is not, then it displays error_message_1
> - if B is true and A is not, it displays error_message_2
> - if both A and B are NOT true, displays error_message_3

Is best written with the last condition first:

```
if (!A && !B) {                 // both are false
    display(error_message_3);
} else if (!A) {                // if A is false here, B must be true
    display(error_message_2);  
} else if (!B) {                // if B is false here, A must be true
    display(error_message_1);
} else {                        // both are true
    display(no_error);
}
```

Comment: *Is best written with the last condition first* Maybe, but why?

Comment: @torazaburo This is self-evident if one thinks about it for a minute. :) Sometimes things need to leave a wide enough gap to incite the OP to think about it and jump over it on their own terms. (I even included comments in the code as a handrail here)

Answer (score -1):

The conditions that you asked are :

if A is true and B is not, then it displays error_message_1

if B is true and A is not, it displays error_message_2

if both A and B are NOT true, displays error_message_3

To check if something is true you need to check if it equals to one, not zero.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Travel Agency</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculatePrice() {

    var tourType;
    var payDate;
    var returnTrip;
    var extra = 0;
    var tourCost = 0;
    var discount = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        tourType = document.getElementById("ans" + i);
            if (tourType.checked == true) {
                tourCost += parseFloat(tourType.value);
            }
    }

    if (tourCost == 1 && discount !== 1) {
        alert("Please select a Tour type");
        return;
    }

    for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
        payDate = document.getElementById("date" + a);
        if (payDate.checked == true) {
            discount += parseFloat(payDate.value);
        }
    }

    if (discount == 1 && tourType !== 1) {
        alert("Please select a Payment date.");
        return;
    }

    for (var u = 1; u <= 1; u++) {
        returnTrip = document.getElementById("return" + u);
        if (returnTrip.checked == true) {
            extra += parseFloat(returnTrip.value);
        }
    }

    tourCost = tourCost - discount * tourCost + extra
    tourCost = parseInt(tourCost)
        if (tourCost !== 1 && discount !== 1) {
            alert("Please select a Tour Type and Payment Date.");
            return; }
        else {
            alert("The approximate cost of the holiday is $" + tourCost);
            return; }

    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <p>Complete the form</p>

    <form name="packages">

        <p>
            Tour type:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans1" value="3900"><label for="ans1">5-day Escape Tour</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans2" value="5100"><label for="ans2">7-day Splendour Tour</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="tour" id="ans3" value="6600"><label for="ans3">10-day Best Tour</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            Payment date:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date1" value="0.1"><label for="date1">Before 1st November 2016</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date2" value="0.07"><label for="date2">Between 1st November and 31st December 2016</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date3" value="0.05"><label for="date3">After 31st December 2016</label>
        </p>

        <p> 
            <label for="return1">Click here if you want to include a return airfare from Australia:</label><input type="checkbox" name="return" id="return1" value="900"> 
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculatePrice();"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </p>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
Hey guys, basically what i tried to do at first was to see whether any radio buttons were selected and based my if conditions on those. i tried using `if (button.selected)` but since each radio button has a different id, it was too long and i didn't know how to group them into one variable which i can use.

Comment: Those costs are actual numbers where the value matters. Comparing them to 1 doesn't make any sense